# Can an XNA Game use IsolatedStorageSettings for WP7?

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I've been trying to port some Windows Phone 7 code between Silverlight to XNA which relies on IsolatedStorageSettings but I can't get Visual Studio to resolve it. When I have a look at what Intellisense is resolving under System.IO.IsolatedStorage & it lists IsolatedStorageFile, IsolatedStorageException & IsolatedStorageStream.

The documentation says that the supported version is for Silverlight but I don't understand why I am seeing the difference because of the project types.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.IO.ISOLATEDSTORAGE.ISOLATEDSTORAGESETTINGS);k(ISOLATEDSTORAGESETTINGS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.IO.ISOLATEDSTORAGE.ISOLATEDSTORAGESETTINGS%29;k%28ISOLATEDSTORAGESETTINGS%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Thanks

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.Windows.dll ? That is where the IsolatedStorage types are defined.

Comment: No, I didn't have a reference to that. I thought it didn't need it because I was able to resolve the other items under that namespace without it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following work for me in an XNA project with no extra project references:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    store.CreateFile("folder/file.ext");
}
```

After adding a reference to `System.Windows.dll` I can then do:

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings.Add("something", "myValue");
settings.Save();
```

If you can't get the above working, can you post an example of what you're trying.